# xampp apache not running

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I want to install wordpress on localhost

I have downloaded and installed **XAMPP**.

I have downloaded the wordpress 3.4.1 and placed it in htdocs folder.and i renamed it as demo_folder.

when i type in navigation bar **localhost/demo_folder**  it shows **Unable to connect** page.

As you can see the apache is  not running as shown in fig.

[image]

when i click on start it doesnt get started

I dont know why?

can anyone help me out???

**EDIT1**

the below is netstat -an cmd screenshot

[image]

Comment: ps. do know that that's an ancient version of WP

Comment: oh its 3.4.1 i have edited the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem with XAMPP/Windows. The usual suspect is that there is another application running on port 80, which you should terminate. Also please use the [web](https://www.google.com/search?q=xampp%20apache%20wont%20start), there is a wealth of information on this topic.

To view all currently open ports and the PID of the process using that port, open **cmd** and run

```
> netstat -o
```

This should help with changing the port Apache runs on: http://www.geckoandfly.com/7491/xampp-apache-wont-start-change-port-to-listen-85/ .

Comment: thanks @paislee how will i come to know which other application is running on port 80?and is it possible to change apache port no. while xampp installation?

Comment: the port 80 is already occupied
so i tried changing it to 85 ..but no success :(

Comment: @pradnya what's it occupied by? try terminating that process with the task manager.

Comment: @pradnya see http://msgboard.alphasoftware.com/alphaforum/showthread.php?57516-How-to-determine-what-software-is-using-port-80-(or-any-other-port)&s=22507e0213f3f9d94376929c08e47e2b&p=366043&viewfull=1#post366043

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14423/discussion-between-pradnya-and-paislee)

Comment: hey can we have a chat session regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 7, shut down the Web Deployment Agent Service.  That should clear port 80.

Comment: Look for the World Wide Web Publishing Service, or try 'net stop W3SVC' from a command prompt

Comment: the output that  I get is "the specified service doesnt exists"

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP does have some problems with Windows. You could also try using WAMP. It seems to be a lot easier to install and use.

As for XAMPP, try making sure nothing else is using the port 80.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have tried to install the XAMP multiple times or PORT 80 has been used by other Application. If you are sure other applications is not using the Port 80 try this:

Close the XAMP and go to run and type services.msc and find the service named Apache 2.x.x etc go to its properties and get the exact name of it . For eg, mysql service name is mysql.

After you have found the service name , Open cmd with administrator privilege and type
sc delete apache
here is the manual to delete the service name :
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742045(v=ws.10).aspx

after deleting the service name try opening the XAMP and click on Start next to Apache, hope it will be running now.

If nothing works above ,most of the cases I have seen Skype is the problem:

Go to Tools>Options>Advanced>Connections

Untick Use Port 80 for incoming connections